# possible to see how long it took to send a packet in java

Tags: java, sockets

I made a program in java. I use sockets to let the different programs communicate with each other. My question is: Is it possible to see how long it took to send a packet in milliseconds or even more precise. So from Socket.writeObject(Object) to Socket.readObject(Object).

Answer (score 1):

You could use this kind of code to get elapsed time :

```
long startTime = new Date().getTime();
Socket.writeObject(Object)
...
Socket.readObject(Object)
long endTime = new Date.getTime();
long difference = endTrim-startTime; //difference in milliseconds
```

If you want the time from the server, you need to send a request to the server and have the server send the time back in the response. This could be done with a web service or a simple HTTP request.

Comment: But the problem here is that if the client changes his time it won't be correct.

Comment: See the edited answer, if you want server time you need to send a request to the server (wich can answer you with the current time of the server in the response). It's a bit more complicated but the way of doing it stays the same.